# Route specific application through a SOCKS5 proxy

Tags: linux, networking, proxy

I need to route a specific set of Linux applications through a proxy. Only processes with those names should be rerouted, all other applications in the system should ignore the proxy and work as usual. `proxychains <myapp> <args>` and `tsocks <myapp> <args>` are no option - I need to be able to debug those applications, so they have to be launched on its own. Is it possible?

Comment: https://github.com/darkk/redsocks . This uses iptables to intercept, instead of library interception. Now the difficulty is to pick specific applications. You can check uid/gid (possibly changing the gid, but with setgid, usually debugging will then require root). My personal choice would be to create a separate network namespace (and all the required configuration) to easily separate them. Good luck